# How to get refs element in scoped slot

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

If there are some refs in slot's template, how can I access these refs from the component? For example:

### v-component.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
   export default {
       created() {
           console.log(this.$refs.ele)
       }
   }
</script>
```

### app.vue

```
<template>
    <v-component>
       <template slot-scope="props">
          <h1 ref="ele"></h1>
       </template>
    </v-component>
</template>
<script>
   import VComponent from './v-component
   export default {
       components: { VComponent }
   }
</script>
```

this.$refs.ele in v-compoent.vue output undefined. My question is how can I get this element?

Answer (score 9):

Each element in named `slot` and `scopedSlot` has `context.$refs`.
Do not forget to check if object exists first.

```
<template>
    <v-component>
        <template slot-scope="props">
            <h1 ref="ele">{{ props }}</h1>
        </template>
    </v-component>
</template>
<script>
import VComponent from './v-component'
export default {
    components: { VComponent }
}
</script>
```

and

```
<template>
    <div>
        <slot demo="foo"></slot>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    created() {
        this.$nextTick(function() { // lazy
            console.warn(this.$scopedSlots.default()[0].context.$refs)
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

Result:

[image: result]

Comment: If you have no idea how to get prop you need, just use `console.warn(this)` and explore your vue object in devtools.

Comment: But `this.$slots.default` return undefined and this is a scoped slot not named slot.

Comment: Updated. You need to remove template tag inside template.

Comment: `<slot name="default"> === <slot>`

Comment: This is the named slot's solution, but if in scoped slot, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: See updated code: use `this.$nextTick` and `this.$scopedSlots`. H1 inner text is `<h1>{"demo": "foo"}</h1>` and console has `$refs.ele` object.

Answer (score 2):

This is considered as a bad idea by Vue developers: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7661

Btw, in my case in Vue3, the `el` entries of my slots retrieved by

```js
this.$refs.myRef.$slots['my-slot']().el
```

is always null (as `appContext`)

Answer (score 1):

On Vue 2 you can do this on mounted

```
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$slots)
  },
```

with more precision

You can do this

```
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$slots.name_of_your_slot)
  },
```